# JavaScript: Retry asynchronous readFile() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I want to read a file with javascript. This file has to be downloaded first and is not immediately available. That means if an access to this file with readFile() fails and ends up in the catch block, then this action should be repeated.

```
const fse = require('fs-extra')

let retries = 0
function read_a_file(path) {
    return fse.readFile(path)
        .catch(error => {
            if (retries < 5) {
                retries++
                console.log('Retry', retries)
                setTimeout(() => read_a_file(path), 1000);
            } else {
                console.log(error.message)
            }
        })
}

read_a_file('path/to/file').then(content => {
    console.log('Content:', content)
})
```

The output of this function is:

```
Retry 1
Content: undefined
Retry 2
Retry 3
Retry 4
Retry 5
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'path/to/file'
```

I would now have expected the content (in this case undefined) to be output at the end of all retries. Why is it issued before the first repetition?

Comment: I would assume that’s the return from the first promise.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => read_a_file(path), 1000);` creates a new promise without `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new promises in the setTimeout that have nothing to do with the initial promise you returned.

I would creae a Promise and return that. The readFile would call that promise's resolve or reject.

```js
const fse = require('fs-extra')

function read_a_file(path) {

  let retries = 0
  const readFile(resolve, reject) {
    fse.readFile(path)
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(error => {
        if (retries < 5) {
          retries++
          console.log('Retry', retries)
          setTimeout(() => readFile(resolve, reject), 1000);
        } else {
          console.log(error.message)
          reject(error);
        }
      })
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => readFile(resolve, reject));

}

read_a_file('path/to/file')
  .then(content => {
    console.log('Content:', content)
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.then` in the first call only, so the content logging function will only work once.

```
read_a_file('path/to/file').then(content => {
    console.log('Content:', content)
})
```

Your other call to the function is `setTimeout(() => read_a_file(path), 1000);`, if you add a `.then` after that as well, it will also log it after the other promises resolve. You'll get 5 of those outputs then.